# Boot - Asus motherboard boot opens up bios instead booting - occasionally

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, motherboard, bios, uefi

I have a system runs on windows-8.1, Asus motherboard(UEFI supported). Occasionally(at least once per boot) it opens up bios settings menu instead booting. It shows two boot device (i) HDD with windows, (ii) Windows boot manager. 
When i choose 'Exit and discard changes', screen off few seconds and again shows the same screen or main screen of bios settings.(Motherboard has two screens, quick bios settings, from there one can open advanced bios settings).
If I power off system and boot again it may boot. Sometimes it don't boot up for 5-7 power off.

If I Use live-**Ubuntu USB then it will normally boot**.

**What I have tried?**

1. Changed boot order - no effect.
2. Update bios - Successfully updated, but no change in behavior.
3. Try to change boot override(Set windows boot manager as first) - But it is not allowed.
4. When I enable CSM(compatibility support module) it will show boot menu once, then boot up.

Is there any way to solve this, so that it run windows instead bios setup menu?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a physical HDD and not flash based storage such as an SSD? I have had something similar like this in the past with an older physical Hard Drive as well, and assumed this was because the hard drive was too slow, or the bios too fast to look for an OS. Maybe look for an HDD timeout or delay in the Bios.(https://www.seagate.com/be/nl/support/kb/computer-wont-boot-or-drive-is-not-detected-after-cold-boot-but-is-after-warm-boot-or-reset-209171en/)

Might also want to check the drive is not dying with S.M.A.R.T. data.

Comment: Yes it is physical HDD, and S.M.A.R.T status also shows caution. So, it is the only possible reason? You said 'HDD timeout or delay' - can we change that value to look up for HDD in bios?

Comment: @LaraFlow
In that case you should really replace the drive. I'm not saying it is the only possible reason, but highly likely. For now, you can try to find such a value in the BIOS and modify it if your BIOS has it. I'm not sure if it is a yes/no toggle or a numerical value. But just make sure to increase the timeout so you give the drive enough time to spin up and the BIOS enought time to look for an OS.